# I want to translate this line to the Swift 3 current syntax code but seems there are some problems

Tags: swift

```
CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size), cgImage)
```

When I change the code to this

```
CGContext.draw(imageContext as! CGImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size), byTiling: cgImage)
```

This error is showing

> Cannot convert value of type `CGImage` to expected type `Bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `byTiling` expects a bool value, telling it whether to tile the `image` (in your case `imageContext as! CGImage`) or not.

You can see the description [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/2427134-draw)

So try either setting that bool value or try using the method that @pgdev suggests perhaps.

Hope that helps you.